# Command line to change path to .mdb file for MS Access ODBC System DSN?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, dsn

What odbcconf.exe command line can I use to change the path to the MS Access .mdb file for an already existing System DSN?

Comment: Are you sure you need a DSN? Why not use DSN-less connections in your app, which then gives you full control over the path used at runtime? Your user might not have permission to alter the DSN, for instance.

Comment: Pretty sure.  I'm working with an existing, well-established app that does use DSN connections, and I'm writing tests for that app.

Comment: Just because it has a DSN doesn't mean you have to use it -- you can use a DSN-less connect string and avoid the outside dependence on the DSN entirely. Instructions for within Access at http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, here is a solution using odbcconf.exe instead of going straight to the registry:

```
odbcconf.exe configsysdsn ^
  "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" ^
  "DSN=OurConnectionName;DBQ=X:\Path\to\OurMsAccessDB.mdb"
```

Two items of note which had me tripped up for a while:

- make sure you use 64bit odbcconf.exe when on a 64bit system, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing.
- use `DBQ=` and not `Database=` for the mdb path. When using the latter everything appears to work, however the connection link is named but not actually defined in the ODBC Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do it by changing the registry. Something along the lines of this example taken from the net that I have used before

```
rem -----Author: Jim Michaels
rem -----copy the drivers where all good little ODBC drivers go
if errorlevel 1 goto bye
copy myodbcd.dll C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM
if errorlevel 1 goto bye
rem ----create a .REG file to make registry entries
echo REGEDIT4>myodbc.reg
echo.>>myodbc.reg
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL]>>myodbc.reg
echo "APILevel"="2">>myodbc.reg
echo "ConnectFunctions"="YYN">>myodbc.reg
echo "Driver"="C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM\\myodbc.dll">>myodbc.reg
echo "DriverODBCVer"="02.50">>myodbc.reg
echo "FileExtns"="*.txt">>myodbc.reg
echo "FileUsage"="0">>myodbc.reg
echo "Setup"="C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM\\myodbc.dll">>myodbc.reg
echo "SQLLevel"="1">>myodbc.reg
echo.>>myodbc.reg
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers]>>myodbc.reg
echo "MySQL"="Installed">>myodbc.reg
echo.>>myodbc.reg
rem -----install the registry entries by executing the .REG file
start /wait myodbc.reg
rem ----clean up after we are done installing
del myodbc.reg
:bye
```

If you look at your existing DSN config in the registry then you will get an idea of how to modify the code to suit your situation

Comment: Perfect!  I found the exact place that the .mdb path was stored, in the REG_SZ value "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\\[System DSN Name]\DBQ".  Thank you!

Comment: I think it's crazy to modify the registry for something that is an outside dependency that you don't even need in the first place, i.e., you don't need a DSN at all.

Comment: For better or for worse, my app-under-test already uses DSN connections, and I'm not in a position to change that code.  I just want to switch out the .mdb file, without the app even knowing, to test the app using different datasets.  In the test scripts I'm writing, I'm not even establishing a connection, so DSN vs. DSN-less doesn't really come into play for me here.

Comment: If you're using the DSN, you're establishing a connection, just not necessarily in code.